# Integrating ERDDAP with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, netcdf

I have deployed a ERDDAP server on a AWS machine, which has multiple datasets, each of which contains multiple NetCDF files. I'm trying to develop a JavaScript interface, using Leaflet, so that I can plot the data on the .nc files in a map. However, I'm not being able to do it.

Do you have any idea of how I can do so?

I have a selector in HTML to select a parameter and date, and the following JavaScript code. However, when I acces the web app, the map is not being shown properly, and no data is plotted.

[image: The map is cutted and no data is shown]

```
    // Inicializar el mapa
          var map = L.map('map', {
          center: [-5, 35],
          zoom: 4
        });

    // Agregar capa base
    var layer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
    });

    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Obtain data
    function obtenerDatos(parametro, ano, mes) {
      // URL
      var url = `https://http://13.53.65.240:8080/erddap/files/${parametro}gridtemp/${parametro}_${ano}${mes}.nc`;

      // GET request
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.onload = function() {
        // Decodificar la respuesta
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        // Return data
        return response;
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    // Parameter selector
    var selectorParametros = document.getElementById('parameter');

        // Listener for Parameter selector
    selectorParametros.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var parametro = selectorParametros.value;
      var data = data.value;

      var datos = obtenerDatos(parametro, data.split('-')[0], data.split('-')[2]);

      actualizarCapa(datos);
    });
    
    
    // Date selector
    var selectorData = document.getElementById('data');
    
    // Listener for date selector
    selectorData.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var parametro = parametro.value;
      var data = selectorData.value;

      var datos = obtenerDatos(parametro, data.split('-')[0], data.split('-')[2]);

      actualizarCapa(datos);
    });

    // Update layer
    function actualizarCapa(datos) {
      // Create data layer
      var gridLayer = L.gridLayer(datos, {
        columns: ['latitude', 'longitude', 'CO_column_data_density'],
        style: function(feature) {
          return {
            color: feature.properties.CO_column_data_density
          };
        }
      });

      // Add layer to map
      map.addLayer(gridLayer);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. What did you try? Share the code snippet. Why can't you plot the data? Do you face any error?

Comment: I @Padmanabha , I've edited the original post :)

Comment: Is OSM tile layer displayed correctly if you omit grid layer?

Comment: No, even if I comment the line `map.addLayer(gridLayer);` , it isn't displayed correctly

Comment: I managed to display the map correctly, I was missing the CSS from leaflet. However, no data is being shown on the map. How can you add data directly from a gridded nc file?

Comment: You can't. I know of no Leaflet plugin that would support displaying NetCDF in a browser. The only possible way of displaying NetCDF files in a browser that I know of is through ncWMS service, see https://reading-escience-centre.gitbooks.io/ncwms-user-guide/content/.

Comment: But, given that the data in the NetCDF files is gridded and delimited in a zone, wouldn't it be possible to create a geoJSON file and map the data from the files onto the geoJSON?

Comment: That's exactly what ncWMS service I mentioned is doing, but for raster WMS format. Yes, it can be done, so either you'll have to do it or find someone else who had done already done it.